# Export image with GDAL. Poor quality

Tags: arcgis, tiff, gdal, arcmap

I use the following command to export a jpg file:

```
gdaldem color-relief C:\input.tif C:\colors.txt C:\output.jpg
```

The file colors.txt:

```
-0.99 255 38 0
-0.5 255 81 0
-0.3 255 119 0
-0.2 255 153 0
-0.1 255 187 0
-0 255 221 0
0.1 255 255 0
0.2 206 224 0
0.3 164 196 0
0.4 122 171 0
0.5 85 145 0
0.6 48 120 0
1 0 97 0
```

The problem is that the file looks different when I display it in the standard Windows software to display images or when I show it in arcmap.

This is how it looks good and is shown in arcmap:
[ARCMAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqmIG.jpg)

This is how it is displayed in the Windows program:
[WINDOWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZU3Z.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea how to display this in Windows software as it appears in arcmap software?

Thanks

Comment: try to export as PNG

Comment: I tried. Same result :/

Comment: What about exporting as tiff?

Comment: The output is completely black. All values are zero. very weird..